# Power BI Row-level Security roles

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security

I want to get some insight on the Row-level security roles on PowerBI. We need to upload a dashboard to a workspace that is linked to a sort of PowerBI online/Service. The problem is that as we tested we found the following:

- On PowerBI Desktop, when we use the User = username() our username is returned (Domain\windows username)
- On PowerBI Service the User = username() measure returns our corporate e-mail.
- On our workspace the same measure returns an encrypted username.
  We tried using the user = userprincipalname() and as expected on the Desktop and Service version, it returns the e-mail, but still we are not able to see that returning on our internal workspace.

So the question here would be, despite the fact that the userprincipalname() measure returns the same code that the username(), is it possible to use it anyways and to filter based on the UPN?

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-nz/blog/using-username-in-dax-with-row-level-security/

Comment: You should user the userprincipalname(), to drive the security. The 2nd link is from 2016 is an old way of doing RLS

Comment: @Jon so if I use the userprincipalname() and base the security per email, it doesn't matter that our Workspace recognizes the upn as a set of characters?

Comment: You need to post an image or example of what it is showing. It should just reveal the upn. Are you using Azure Active Directory?